# Sidekiq throws 'Active Record Unknown Primary Key Error' on Active Type object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, sidekiq

I am using the [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) gem in my Rails app to handle some long-running processes asynchronously. As illustrated in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast), a reference to the model to be processed is passed as an argument to the `perform_async` method of the worker class doing the background processing.

This would not be a problem if the model in question was an Active Record object. However it is an [Active Type](http://github.com/makandra/active_type) object designed to "quack like ActiveRecord" and unfortunately it does not quack as loudly so I get an `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKeyError`.

How do I set a primary key for a Ruby object that really is not a db object and convince Sidekiq to treat it as such? Unable to glean information on how to do this from the Active Type Github page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to do with your Active Type Object.
As the [Documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple) states

> The arguments you pass to `perform_async` must be composed of **`simple`** JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and hash.

If you don't have an id to identify the Object( from your post I understand that you don't), then the best solution would be to convert the Object to a Hash and then pass it to `perform_async` . But as I said, it depends on what you data you need from your Object. In some cases you might not need to use a hash and a simpler data type will suffice.

Comment: So I am passing the title attribute of the Active Type Object, a string, to `perform_async` in the absence of an id. But this problem isn't about not having an id, it is about not having a primary key a la an Active Type Object. I have just tried using Sidekiq with an actual Active Record object and it worked perfectly. What I'm wondering then is if there is any way to make the Active Type object more Active Record like by setting a p key. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to do `self.primary_key = :title` in `active_type_object.rb` but that didn't work